# How to keep a swing component updated

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree

One of my classes is returning a JPanel which is added on a JFrame by some other class.
The JPanel contains a JTree and some buttons. On some events the panel is created again and returned to the JFrame.

My problem is that I have to add the JPanel to the Container of the JFrame again and then resize the frame for changes to be visible. I can't figure how to have the frame update without resizing.I tried removing old objects and adding updated ones but still doesn't work.

What is the best way to deal with this issue? Ideally I would have a reference to the JPanel and when the JPanel is changed, the frame will also be updated.

Comment: The container doesn't seem to have that method . You don't mean invalidate() right ?

Comment: _contents of the JTree change_  Sounds like your treemodel implementation is invalid in that it doesn't notify its listeners about the change/s

Comment: @maple_shaft revalidate is only needed after adding/removing components, not on model changes nor on changing properties on a component

Comment: It seems that changes are happening but are on different layer or something(if I resize the window I can see them) even without repaint.So the problem is how to remove the old pane

Comment: @latusaki Do you change the component or change the model underneath? As kleopatra already said changing the data should reflect itself automatically without any repaint or invalidate.

Comment: what you are seeing is a clear indication of what I guessed: your _model_ doesn't notify its listeners. Fix that and all will be fine :-)

Comment: updated last comment. Post an answer if you know whats wrong so I can accept ^^

Comment: @atusaki look back to your previous question, I'm not lucky with that but as I mentioned everything depends of ...., please post http://sscce.org/

Comment: Kleopatra has already told you what's wrong -- have you fixed it? Have you tried having the model notify its listeners? Do that and it should probably work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The whole model is changing not just its data. I will probably change this in the future but for now when data change a new JTree is created

Then your code should be something like:

```
JTree tree = new JTree( theNewModel );
scrollPane.setViewportView( tree );
```

That is you need to add the new JTree to the GUI, you can't just change the reference to the tree variable.

Or even easier, you don't need to create a new JTree, just replace the model in the existing tree using:

```
tree.setModel( theNewModel );
```

If this still doesn't help then you need to post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem because your question still isn't clear.

Comment: scrollPane.getViewport().getView();

Comment: my day of lost bets (with myself) - this time on the existence of scrollPane.getViewportView :-) Again astonished about asymetric core api ...

Comment: @kleopatra, thats what I typed the first time but then I rechecked the API to find it missing as well ;-)

Answer (score -2):

try `JFrame.invalidate()` first, then call `JFrame.validate()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate%28%29

Comment: -1, Swing uses MVC design. As has already been mentioned in the comments it is the responsibility of the model to notify the view that the data has changed so the view can repaint itself. You don't repaint or revalidate() then entire frame just because you made a change to the model of one of the components on the frame. There is a design problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: The whole model is changing not just its data. I will probably change this in the future but for now when data change a new JTree is created.